# Change Namespaces at RunTime in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamic, namespaces, runtime

I would first like to state I do not need this or plan to implement this; this is a pure "What If" or "Can You Do It" scenario.

If I have a C# Class like below:

```
Namespace Test
{
    public static class TestClass
    {
    }
}
```

Is there a way at runtime to change the namespace of "Test" to any other string?

Normally you would call `Test.TestClass`, what I am wondering is if you can do some sort of reflection or runtime assembly manipulation to change that call to like `NewNameSpace.TestClass`?

Thanks!

I love to learn this stuff!

Comment: That's the trouble with hypothetical questions, it is always unclear if a *real* .NET feature could qualify.  Look at type forwarding: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177220.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears through no responses here and research of my own, that this is not possible.